# не получает данные с json

Tags: jquery, json

есть форма для заполнения, надо отправить данные через json в скрипт, но не получается

пробовал через , data: formData, но выдает ошибку 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'error' => 'Ошибка при разборе параметров: не указана или некорректно указана фамилия пользователя!',
))

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="myForm">
            <div class="field-block" style="font-size:14px">

                <input id="LASTNAME" class="field" name="LASTNAME" required type="text" placeholder="Иванов">
            </div>
                    <div class="field-block" style="font-size:14px">

                <input id="FIRSTNAME" class="field" name="FIRSTNAME" required type="text" placeholder="Иван">
            </div>
                    <div class="field-block" style="font-size:14px">

                <input id="PARENTNAME" class="field" name="PARENTNAME" required type="text" placeholder="Иванич">
            </div>

                <div class="field-block" style="font-size:14px">
                            <input id="PHONE" class="field" name="PHONE" type="text" placeholder="9620000000">
            </div>
                <div class="field-block" style="font-size:14px">
                            <input id="BIRTHDAY" class="field" name="BIRTHDAY" required type="text" placeholder="23.06.1989">
            </div>
                <div class="field-block" style="font-size:14px">
                <input id="check" name="check" checked type="checkbox">
                <span class="check-text">Я добровольно отправляю свои данные</span>
            </div>
            <button id="button1" class="t-btn" type="submit" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#df2322;border-radius:30px; -moz-border-radius:30px; -webkit-border-radius:30px;"><table style="width:100%; height:100%;"><tbody><tr><td>Оформить онлайн</td></tr></tbody></table></button>

            <div class="result">

            </div>
        </form>
        <script>

        $(function() {
            $("#myForm").submit(function() {
                var formData = {
                    "LASTNAME":$("#LASTNAME").val()
                    , "FIRSTNAME":$("#FIRSTNAME").val()
                      , "PARENTNAME":$("#PARENTNAME").val()
                        , "PHONE":$("#PHONE").val()
                          , "BIRTHDAY":$("#BIRTHDAY").val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url:'register.php'
                    , type:'POST'
                    , data: $.toJSON(formData)
                    , success: function(res) {
                        alert(res);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

вот файл register.php

```
    $myCurl = curl_init();
    $rawdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $params =json_decode($rawdata);  

    $LASTNAME =$params->LASTNAME; 
    $FIRSTNAME =$params->FIRSTNAME; 
    $PARENTNAME =$params->PARENTNAME; 
    $BIRTHDAY =$params->BIRTHDAY; 
    $PHONE =$params->PHONE; 

    $data_string='';

    $data_string = $data_string . '<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins="сайт.ru/">';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<x:Header/>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<x:Body>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<ins:ExecProc>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<ins:pData>';

    $data_string = $data_string . '<![CDATA[';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<data>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<request>';
        $data_string = $data_string . '<RequestIp>тут айпи</RequestIp>';
        $data_string = $data_string . '<AppId>а тут айди</AppId>';
        $data_string = $data_string . '<reqName>WC_USERREGISTRATION</reqName>';
        $data_string = $data_string . '<params>';
            $data_string = $data_string . ' <LASTNAME>' . $LASTNAME .'</LASTNAME>';
            $data_string = $data_string . ' <FIRSTNAME>' . $FIRSTNAME .'</FIRSTNAME>';
            $data_string = $data_string . ' <PARENTNAME>' . $PARENTNAME .'</PARENTNAME>';
            $data_string = $data_string . ' <BIRTHDAY>' . $BIRTHDAY .'</BIRTHDAY>';
            $data_string = $data_string . ' <PHONE>' . $PHONE .'</PHONE>';
        $data_string = $data_string . '</params>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '</request>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '</data>';
    $data_string = $data_string . ']]>';

    $data_string = $data_string . '</ins:pData>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '</ins:ExecProc>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '</x:Body>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '</x:Envelope>';

    //echo $data_string;


    //echo "\n\n";

    curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'сайт/webservice/файлик.asmx',

        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST=> "POST",  
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',                                                                                
        'SOAPAction: сайт.ru/ExecProc',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
        CURLOPT_POST => true
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($myCurl);
    curl_close($myCurl);

    $xml=simplexml_load_string ($response, NULL, NULL, "сайт);
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace("md", "сайт"); 
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"); 
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); 
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

    $soapResult =$xml->xpath('//md:ExecProcResult//data');

    //var_dump($soapResult);
    //echo "\n\n";

    if(count($soapResult)>0){
        if(!isset($soapResult[0]->error)){
            echo json_encode(array("message"=>$soapResult[0]->result->msg->__toString()));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("error"=>$soapResult[0]->error->fulltext->__toString()));
        }
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("error"=>"Не понятная ошибка"));
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Так у Вас же не JSON, а XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по закомментаренным строкам

```
//echo $data_string;
//echo "\n\n";
```

frontend вы уже отлаживали, и видели, что ожидаемые параметры передавались.
Если нет, то зачем тогда код SOAP запроса. Он ведь не при чём?

А если все же параметры через JSON передаются, но SOAP запрос все равно не проходит, то начните отладку с замены переменных в SOAP запросе в `register.php` на текстовые константы, лучше латиницей. Если запрос будет принят, попробуйте текстовые константы кириллицей. Если и этот будет принят - вот тогда проверяйте frontend.

Вообще, можно запускать curl прямо с консоли сервера, если есть доступ. Или можно поставить curl под Windows и использовать его...